# The completion of the space of finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, lie-groups, finite-groups, geometric-group-theory

**Edit:** I revise the  question based on the comment  conversations

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be  the set of  all equivalence classes  of  finite  groups under the "Isomorphism" equivalence relation.
We  define a  pseudo metric  $d$  on $\mathcal{F}$ as  follows:

$$d(G,H)= \inf \{Hd(\tilde {G}_{n},\tilde{H}_{n})\} $$

where  $\inf$ is taken  over all arbitrary   isomorphic  copies $\tilde{G}_{n}$  and  $\tilde{H}_{n}$ of  $G$ and  $H$ in   $Gl(n,\mathbb{R})$, respectively, while $Hd$ is the Hausdorff distance   in $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ induced by its standard left  invariant  metric.

The  definition of  this  metric  is  motivated  by the  Hausdorff Gromov  metric  on the  space  of  compact  Riemannian  manifolds.

> Is $d$   a  metric  on $\mathcal{F}$? If  the  answer  is  yes, we  denote by  $\bar{\mathcal{F}}$ the   completion of $\mathcal{F}$. What  can be  said about  an object $Z$ in  $\bar{\mathcal{F}}$?

Can one  consider  the unit circle, in some reasonable  sense, as  an  object in this completion?
Is there  a  natural group  structure  on every element $Z\in \bar{\mathcal{F}}$? Is there  a  natural topology on $Z$?

Is  $\bar{\mathcal{F}}$ a  compact space?

Comment: I'm not sure what you call "standard left-invariant metric" on $GL_n(\mathbf{R})$. I'm not aware of such a metric (there are plenty of left-invariant Riemannian metric and also some non-Riemannian ones, you have to simultaneously choose one for each $n$)

Comment: @YCor  the invariant Riemannian metric on $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ as a Lie group which restrict to $tr(AB^{tr})$ on the tangent space at neutral element.

Comment: How exactly do the Cantor set and the unit circle appear? A priori points of $\bar{\mathcal F}$ are equivalence classes of sequences of isomorphism classes of finite groups. Presumably by the unit circle you mean the point represented by the sequence $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, $n=1,2,...$? But in what sense can it be identified with the unit circle? Why not $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ for example? Maybe there is some other non-equivalent sequence which "fills more gaps in the circle"? Say, does the sequence of dihedral groups produce the same point of the completion? Or not?

Comment: The usual way of generalizing Gromov--Hausdorff convergence to groups is via the Grigorchuk--Gromov space of *marked groups*. A marked group is a group together with a chosen finite generating set. A marked group corresponds canonically to a normal subgroup of a free group $F_n$. The space of marked groups of rank $n$ is the space of all normal subgroups of $F_n$, with the topology restricted from the natural product topology on the power set of $F_n$.  In this topology, the closure of the space of finite groups is the space of groups that are *locally emeddable in finite groups* (LEF).

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  thank you  very mich  for  your  very interesting comment. Both sequence(cyclic groups  and  dihedral groups are  equivalents, since both of them are proving that the  unit  circle in $Gl(2, \mathbb{R})$ is totally  bounded. So their  hausdorff   distance tends to zero. But according to your  comment, I understand  my  assertion about the  unit  circle  and the  Cantor  set was not reasonable.I revise the  question. But is The sequence   $S_{n}$ of the  permutation group a  bounded sequence?Is  $\bar{\mathcal{F}}$  a  compact  space?

Comment: @HJRW  Thank  you  very  much  for  your interesting  comment. Is the  topology of the  space  of finite ranked marked group, the  direct  limit  of  topologies  on the  space  of  groups of  rank n? Moreover, do you think that by restriction of  two topologies to the  space  of finite groups, we  get the  same  topology?

Comment: You can certainly define it as a direct limit, though all the papers I know consider fixed $n$.  The set of finite groups is always discrete in this topology, since any finitely presented group has a neighbourhood consisting only of (marked) quotients.  Here's a reference: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401042 .

Comment: There is a subtlety in the Gromov-Hausdorff definition for spaces I think you are overlooking: the triangle inequality only holds because of the flexibility of metric spaces. Namely, given metric spaces $Y_1,Y_2$ and a compact metric space $X$ that isometrically embeds into both, there is a metric space $Y$ given by gluing $Y_1$ to $Y_2$ along $X$ with the property that $Y_1, Y_2$ isometrically embed. One needs to apply this gluing construction with $X$ the middle space in the triangle inequality in order to verify it. Without such a construction for groups, the triangle inequality need't hold

Comment: An alternative way to put a metric on the space of finite groups is as in Borel equivalence relation theory. Namely, the space of finitely generated groups (or more generally the countable groups) can be viewed in several ways as a Polish space, with a complete metric, and the finite groups are a subspace. (In this way of doing things, they do not generally mod out by isomorphism, since they specifically want to investigate the complexity of the isomorphism relation for various kinds of groups.)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins  Professor Hamkins thank you very much for your very interesting comment. I will focus on its details.

Comment: @JHance  Thank you for this very interesting point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i don't think it's a metric. Take a large prime $p$. By embedding $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/(p^2+p)\mathbb Z$ in the circle $S^1 \subseteq GL(2,\mathbb R)$, one sees that the distance between them is at most $O(1/p)$. By embedding $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/(p+1)\mathbb Z$ in the torus $S^1 \times S^1 \subseteq GL(4,\mathbb R)$, one again sees that the distance between them is at most $O(1/p)$.

But of course $\mathbb Z/(p^2+p)$ and $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/(p+1)\mathbb Z$ are isomorphic, so one would be forced to conclude by the triangle inequality that the distance between $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is $O(1/p)$.

But this is false. If they had that distance in some $GL(n,\mathbb R)$, then by pidgeonhole, $p$ different elements of $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ would have to be within $O(1/p)$ of some element of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and hence within $O(1/p)$ of each other. By left invariance, $p$ different elements of $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ would have to be within $O(1)$ of the identity.

But in any representation of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, only $o(p)$ elements have eigenvalues within $o(1/\sqrt{p})$ of the identity, since we can write the representation as a sum of characters, the eigenvalues on each character must be $p$th roots of unity, and each element is determined by its eigenvalues on two independent characters.

So we just need to check that every element within $O(1/p)$ of the identity has eigenvalues within $o(1/\sqrt{p})$ of the identity.

In fact   we  can show more is true, and  an element within $d$ of the identity matrix can't move any vector of length one by a distance of greater than $e^{d}-1$. Since $e^{O(1/p)}-1 = O(1/p) = o(1/\sqrt{p})$, we obtain the desired conclusion. To check this, differentiate $Mv$ with respect to $M$ and observe that its operator norm with respect to your metric is the operator norm of $M$, so if $f(x)$ is the maximum total distance moved a vector of length one by a matrix within $x$ of the identity, $df/dx \leq 1+f$ so $f(x) \leq e^x-1$.

Comment: Thank  you  very  much  for  your  answer. I think you  are  proving that $d$  is not  well defined, since  your  change an equivalent  member. I  am surprised:Because I think it is an immediate  consequence of the  definition that $d$ is  well defined.Let $G, G', H  $ be  three  groups  with $G \simeq G'$. then $d(G,H)\leq d(G',H)$  and  $d(G',H) \leq d(G,H)$. Am I  mistaken?

Comment: @AliTaghavi No, I am proving that it does not satisfy the triangle inequality and hence is not a metric.

Comment: May  I  ask you  to more  explain on "$p$ different elements of $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$ would have to be within $O(1)$ of the identity"?

Comment: @AliTaghavi This follows from left invariance of the metric on $GL_n$. We establish that there is a set $S$ in $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$ of size $p$ where every element is within a distance $d=O(1/p)$ of some element of $GL_n(\mathbb R)$, hence every pair of elements is within a distance $2d$ by each other, hence translating by a fixed element $g \in S$, every element in $g^{-1} S \subseteq \mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$ is in distance $2d$ of the identity.

Comment: Right but  why  you assume that these  p elements lie  in a  $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @AliTaghavi That is another typo, sorry. Fixed now.

Comment: at the same time i am trying to understand details of your answer,  I am curious are there two non isomorphic finite groups with zero distance? Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: @AliTaghavi Probably not. It's easy to prove this if you work in $O(n)$ instead of $GL_n(\mathbb R)$, because then the metric is both left and right invariant, but it should still be true in general - one just needs the right inequality.

Comment: sorry if my question is elementary.Is the contradiction to "O(1)", obvious?(As you pointed out to O(1).

Comment: BTW does your argument of failur of triangle inequality still work if we would define the metric d via O(n) instead of Gl(n, R)?

Comment: @AliTaghavi Yes, it works just as well.

Comment: you pointed out to O(1) and i understant its reason, by p times application of triangle inequality. But you did not finally come back to this O(1) and the contradiction. You just say there are $o(p)$ member whose eigenvalues are within $O(1/\sqrt{p}$ if unity. But what is the relation to O(1). Sorry if these are elementary question.

Comment: @AliTaghavi I realize my big $Os$ and little $O$s are not quite right. Under an assumption (the triangle inequality) we have shown that there are $p$ elements within $O(1/p)$ of the identity. Furthermore, by a counting argument we show that there are $o(p)$ elements with eigenvalues within $o(1/\sqrt{p})$ of the identtiy. Since all elements within $O(1/p)$ of the identity have eigenvalues within $O(1/p)$, and hence $o(1/\sqrt{p})$ of the identit,y we derive a contradiction.